# Python Class - unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Google Sheets I have a list with user responses. Per Google API I am fetching the data from the Google Sheets and putting it into a python list.

I have then defined a class and in this class I am calculating the score of the values.
Upon calling the coreCalc() I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "coreCalc.py", line 52, in <module>
    coreCalc()
  File "coreCalc.py", line 49, in __init__
    print(sum(df_array))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

How can I go about solving this issue, have I ill-defined my class and therefore I couldn't avoid this error?

**my code [excuse the format, I copied from VIM]:**

```
  7 #references
  8 import gspread
  9 from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
 10 import pandas as pd
 11 import csv
 12 import time
 13 import requests
 14 
 15 #use creds to create a client to interact with the Google Drive API
 16 scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
 17          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
 18 creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('/Users/Miauw/Miaauw/github/ComplexService/Token/client_secret.json', scope)
 19 client = gspread.authorize(creds)
 20 
 21 # Find a workbook by name and open the first sheet
 22 sheet = client.open("IFTTT_Webhooks_Events").sheet1
 23 
 24 #get data directly from google sheet.
 25 data = sheet.get_all_values()
 26 headers = data.pop(0)
 27 # capture data into dataframe
 28 df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)
 29 # obtain values from the last row of the spreadsheet. 
 30 df_array = [ (df["Statement 1"].iloc[-1]),
 31     (df["Statement 2"].iloc[-1]),
 32     (df["Statement 3"].iloc[-1]),
 33     (df["Statement 3"].iloc[-1])
 34 ]
 35 
 36 #function for calculating user lonelienss based on UCLA Lonliness scoring (theory) 
 37 class coreCalc:
 38     def __init__(self):
 39     #assign loneliness-scores to the various user-responses
 40         for i in range(len(df_array)):
 41             if df_array[i] == 'Often':
 42                 df_array[i] = 3
 43             elif df_array[i] == 'Sometimes':
 44                 df_array[i] = 2
 45             elif df_array[i] == 'Rarely':
 46                 df_array[i] = 1
 47             elif df_array[i] == 'Never':
 48                 df_array[i] = 0
 49             #obtain sum of values for final scoring
 50                 print(sum(df_array))
 50 
 51
 52  coreCalc()
```

**Additional info:**

If I do print`(df_array)` the result is:

```
['Often', 'Never', 'Never', 'Never']
```

After the assignment of scores I get:

```
[3, 0, 0, 0]
```

And it is of this last list that I want the `sum()`.

Comment: Is the indentation of `print(sum(df_array))` correct? Shouldn' it be in line with the for loop?

Comment: It worked, you were right! VIM complained initially about the wrong indentation so I wrongly extra indented into the wrong hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just bring the print sum outside the for loop so that all your strings are converted to integer before you calculate the final score

```
def __init__(self):
#assign loneliness-scores to the various user-response
     for i in range(len(df_array)):
         if df_array[i] == 'Often':
             df_array[i] = 3
         elif df_array[i] == 'Sometimes':
             df_array[i] = 2
         elif df_array[i] == 'Rarely':
             df_array[i] = 1
         elif df_array[i] == 'Never':
              df_array[i] = 0
     #obtain sum of values for final scoring
     print(sum(df_array))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
temp_list = []    
for i in range(len(df_array)):
    if df_array[i] == 'Often':
        temp_list.append(3)
    elif df_array[i] == 'Sometimes':
        temp_list.append(2)
    elif df_array[i] == 'Rarely':
        temp_list.append(1)
    elif df_array[i] == 'Never':
        temp_list.append(0)
print(sum(temp_list))
```

Comment: See my: Additional Info I added please. The new addition results into: 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "coreCalc.py", line 53, in <module>
    coreCalc()
  File "coreCalc.py", line 50, in __init__
    print(sum(map(int,df_array)))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Never'`

Comment: Still broken (indentation is wrong, it will fail at the first iteration). Also, never call a variable `list`, that's a builtin type name that you're using.

Comment: @PruthviBarot solved, the print() was supposed to be indented under the For.